# NSPredicate to handle NIL string as ANY character

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I have an `NSPredicate` looks like that:

```
NSPredicate *predicateSearch;

    if ([category_array count]>0 && [location_array count]>0) {
        predicateSearch =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category_id IN %@ AND location_id IN %@ AND company_title CONTAINS %@",category_array,location_array,searchStr];
    }
    else if ([category_array count]>0){

         predicateSearch =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category_id IN %@ AND company_title CONTAINS %@",category_array,searchStr];
    }
    else if([location_array count]>0){

        predicateSearch = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"location_id IN %@ AND company_title CONTAINS %@",location_array,searchStr];
    }

    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicateSearch];
```

Since `NSPredicate` is not able to handle `Nil` values I am using this If-Statement to format the Predicate and handle the `Nil`value as 'ANY'.
The issue here is that I want also the searchStr to be handled as 'ANY' if it's `Nil`.
I tried to set it as empty string in case of `Nil` but it won't work.
Is there any way to accomplish that without using any If-statements for each case(9 if-statements it's too much)?

Comment: You can use `andPredicateWithSubpredicates:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use compound predicates.  Example, based on what you posted:

```
NSPredicate *categoryPredicate = (category_array.count > 0)
    ? [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category_id IN %@", category_array]
    : [NSPredicate predicateWithValue:YES];

NSPredicate *locationPredicate = (category_array.count > 0)
    ? [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"location_id IN %@", location_array]
    : [NSPredicate predicateWithValue:YES];

NSPredicate *searchPredicate = (searchStr.length > 0)
    ? [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"company_title CONTAINS %@", searchStr]
    : [NSPredicate predicateWithValue:YES];

NSCompoundPredicate *predicate =
   [NSCompoundPredicate
    andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[                                            
                                    categoryPredicate,
                                    locationPredicate,
                                    searchPredicate,
                                   ]
   ];
```

Comment: Thank you for that great and clean answer. My question is what if I want the searchPredicate to be "OR" instead of other two that had AND comparison

Comment: Just found out about `orPredicateWithSubpredicates`. Thank you

Comment: Also, a compound predicate can be formed with other compound predicates, allowing for arbitrary nesting and grouping of conditions.